# How to return a string from a bash function that contains a filename with spaces?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a function which returns a string which consists of two parts:

1. option switch
2. filename with spaces.

My problem is: How to quote in order to pass the result to another program?

```
#!/bin/bash
getOption() {
  echo "-C $1"
}
# prints first lines of man page of cp (copy) 
man $(getOption "$1") cp | head -10
```

In this sample I'm trying to pass a customized config file to `man`. Assuming the snippet above is named `run.sh`, the customized config is named `my man.conf` and both reside in the same directory I'm getting this error:

```
$ ./run.sh "my man.conf"
my: No such file or directory
Warning: cannot open configuration file my
# output from man for man…
```

---

As *glenn jackman* indicated: I was missing a point of [Bash's docs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

> The root of the issue described above is that you need a way to maintain each argument as a separate word, even if that argument contains spaces. Quotes won't do it, but an array will.

So spaces are preserved when updating to

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("")
addOption() {
  args+=(-C "$1")
  return 0
}

$(addOption "$1")
man "${args[@]}" cp | head -10
```

Comment: Your question is not clear... What is that cp in last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Basically, you need to restructure. Even passing quotes back from the function won't work. This

```
getOption() {
  echo "-C '$1'"
}
```

will just lead to the error message `cannot open configuration file 'my`

Once you concatenate a string containing whitespace into another string, you cannot extract the added string as a single entity.

Given your question, you should simply do

```
man -C "$1" ...
```

But I suspect you want "run.sh" to be more complex than what you've shown. Please provide more details.

Comment: Yes, the intention of the function is to add option and its filename conditionally. The function's result can be part of the command in any case -- as it resolves to a valid option or empty string.

And yes, your suggestion to use an array did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You don't quote, you need to escape spaces on the command line, e.g.:

`./run.sh my\ man.conf`

In most shells, tab completion would help do this for you.

Of course, spaces in file and directory names are semi-evil, and the real fix is to try and avoid these.

p.s. I think your script has other issues besides just getting it the right arguments . . .

Comment: Spaces are not evil and need not be avoided. The real fix is to write programs that are not broken :)

Comment: @ernie thanks for your response. Unfortunately escaping doesn't make a difference: `./run.sh my\ man.conf` = `./run.sh "my man.conf"`

I know the example is artificial but its short and -- I hope -- easy to reproduce. What other issues you find in the sample?